# Getting Started with Python but want to implement Web services with Sql backend

Tags: python, sql-server, django, web-services

I have a mini project that I need to create website site where I can submit some information to a database but want to do it through Web services.

Is there any projects that I can reference or tutorial that shows me how to create a Web front end, python web service or django web services tied MS Sql backend.

I can do it in another language but really want to do it purely in python/Django or whatever framework that make sense to do it in so I can learn.

Answer (score 0):

You can start off by reading the Django tutorial on official website https://www.djangoproject.com

Or read Django by examples. It will set you started with cool features and all you need to build an amazing app quickly. You will be excited after finishing the first  two chapters.

For MySQL follow the documentation and it is pretty easy

Comment: Thank you for your response, i'm going through some tutorials now so far i like it alot